# Echo If Url ending with a +

Tags: if-statement, request, uri

I want to display something if the page url is ending with a +

I tried this :

```
<?php if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],-1) == '+') echo 'lalala'; ?>
```

But it's not working :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Adding a `+` in URL will make the browser jump to another page. Can you give an example of URL ending with `+`?

Comment: If it is something like `http://abc.com/a.php?=haha+`, then it works for me. What do you mean by "not working"?